# What are the benefits of normalizing longitude to [-180, 180)?

Tags: google-maps, extents

In the Google Maps API v2 for Android, [`LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) normalizes longitude values to the range -180 degrees inclusive to +180 degrees *exclusive*.  Consequently, attempting to represent the entire world as a [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds) produces a longitude range of -180 to -180, which has zero width and contains no points:

```
// southwest, northeast
final LatLngBounds world = new LatLngBounds(
    new LatLng(-90, -180),
    new LatLng(90, 180));
assertTrue(world.contains(new LatLng(0, 0))); // test fails
```

So obviously, normalizing longitude to [-180, 180) has a cost in terms of how `LatLngBounds` works.  We can only speculate as to why the API designers might have made this decision.  But what are the potential benefits of normalizing longitude this way?  Are there any common operations that are simplified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+180 and -180 are the same meridian on the Earth, so they are essentially the same value when defining extents. And as you demonstrated, defining extents with the same value will produce zero width extents.

This is why one of the +-180 values must be exclusive and one must be inclusive.

**edit:** Technically, there isn't a reason why they couldn't have +180 and -180 both be valid, but when creating an API, less is more. It's better to restrict input up front, rather than having to deal with multiple cases for the same value in your code.

This is somewhat similar to using [One's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) to store signed integer values. Having to test for two different representations of zero is a pain, so this is one of the reasons why [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is much more popular.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I might have missed the point you were trying to get at. Please leave a comment or edit your question if so.

Comment: Perhaps unintentionally, you hit on exactly what I'm getting at.  As you said, it's necessary for *extents* to be inclusive/exclusive.  But I don't understand what advantage there might be in prohibiting a latitude value of `+180` in single point coordinates, except maybe to slightly simplify testing for equality.  That leads me to wonder if there's some advantage I don't see.

Comment: Possibly to clean up the 'edge' when unprojecting data back to lat-lon. Some projections do not cleanly unproject, so you might start with a line with all x/easting values at -180, but end up with one at -180.xxxx, -179.9999xxxx, +179.99999xxxx, +180.0000xxx, etc.

Comment: I implemented my own equivalents to `LatLng` and `LatLngBounds` and ended up normalizing `180` to `-180` just as Google did.  I realized that allowing `180` was insufficient for the purpose that I originally envisioned (allowing a bounds that spans 360 degrees longitude) so I had to find another solution for that.  Incidentally, I discovered that Google's `LatLng` does *not* normalize `-0.0` to `0.0` and treats them as unequal.  It also accepts `Double.NaN`...